# Line replace two values python django

Tags: python, django

I want to line replace 2 values in the same file. I want to search 'input="Default"' and replace its value with 'This' and pattern="Default" with 'Now'. I have created tmp form where my code reads the values and writes to another file.Am new to django and python.At the moment its writing one value.

views.py

```
with open('/home/usr/dev/Django/rulebase/test_pattern_tmp.rb', 'r') as pattern_reading:
   lines = [line.replace('pattern = "Default"','Now') for line in pattern_reading.readlines()]
   lines = [line.replace('input = "Default"','This') for line in pattern_reading.readlines()]
with open('/home/usr/dev/Django/rulebase/test_pattern.rb', 'w') as pattern_reading:
   pattern_reading.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Please show an example of your data and expected output.

Comment: My data is only two lines. My result is Now on one line and This on line two.

Comment: @sayian101 so you want to replace all occurrences of `pattern = "Default"` with `pattern = "Now"` and `input = "Default"` with `input = "This"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
with open('/home/usr/dev/Django/rulebase/test_pattern_tmp.rb', 'r') as pattern_reading:
    with open('/home/usr/dev/Django/rulebase/test_pattern.rb', 'w') as pattern_writing:
        for line in pattern_reading:
            out=line.replace('pattern="Default"','Now').replace('input="Default"','This')
            pattern_writing.write(out)
```

Hi, there are two issues:

1. you are reading the whole file into memory (which is not necessarily an error)
2. A file object may be considered as an iterator. As soon as you have reached the end of file in your first iteration the secon iteration does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Its writing one value because your `lines` list only contains the last replacement; you need to loop over `lines` in the second statement where you replace `input = "Default"`.

Comment: Am trying to looking for an equivalent to feof in php. So I can apply to my code.